# Would Python be too slow for client-side use in Browsers?

Tags: javascript, python, client-side, client-side-scripting

I’ve heard the statement that `Python` would be too slow to be of any use in browsers.

I reckon `Javascript` is only superior in this aspect because of companies like `Google` who need it fast (and made it fast) because they need it to survive, but I could be wrong.

Are there any differences in how `Python` and `JS` are designed that have an impact on how they (would) perform in browsers?

Comment: It's not really "how fast is this language" but "how many browsers support this language". The answer for Python right now is about zero. (Though there have been interpreted and compiled solutions for that.)

Comment: JavaScript (JS) is an interpreted computer programming language.[5] It was originally implemented as part of web browsers so that client-side scripts could interact with the user, control the browser, communicate asynchronously, and alter the document content that was displayed.[5]

Comment: @WaleedKhan Thanks for knowing better what I should ask then I do. I think it should be on Programmers anyway, so silent retreat.

Answer (score 7):

There is a project named [Brython](http://www.brython.info) designed to replace JavaScript as the scripting language for the web.

Comment: Indeed - I was going to mention Brython - it is a thin translation layer from Python-like Syntax to Javascript that happens in client side, and bring most of the goodies of Python's syntax to the client. (No Python stdlib, though, byut you get a nice and working "import" statement)

Comment: Thanks, but this kind of missed the question. I expanded it to make it more clear.